# multiple definition error while linking C++ project

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm facing this problem while re arranging my C++ project to avoid file name and namespace collision.

So, I replicated the issue on a simple project, Here is the files for it.

File client.hpp:-

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP
#define CLIENT_HPP


namespace work { namespace test {

    int get_age(){
        return 33;
    }

}
}

#endif
```

File work.hpp:-

```
#ifndef WORK_HPP
#define WORK_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "client.hpp"

namespace work { namespace test {

    class NewWork{
        public:
            NewWork(std::string name);
            std::string getName();
            int getAge();
        private:
            std::string _name;
    };
}
}

#endif
```

File work.cpp :-

```
#include "work.hpp"

using namespace work::test;

NewWork::NewWork(std::string name) : _name(name) {}

std::string NewWork::getName() { return _name; }

int NewWork::getAge() { return get_age(); }
```

File main_fun.cpp :-

```
#include "work.hpp"
using namespace work::test;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    NewWork w = NewWork("hari");

    std::cout << "Name: " << w.getName()
        << " Age: " << w.getAge()
        << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

File CMakeLists.txt : -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(work)

set(PROJECT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set ( SRC_FILES 
     ${PROJECT_DIR}/work.cpp
     ${PROJECT_DIR}/main_fun.cpp
     )

 include_directories(${PROJECT_DIR})

 add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
```

So while building this I'm getting the following error :-

```
Linking CXX executable work
CMakeFiles/work.dir/main_fun.cpp.o: In function `work::test::get_age()':
main_fun.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `work::test::get_age()'
CMakeFiles/work.dir/work.cpp.o:work.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [work] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/work.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

One thing I found was, If I make the function work::test::get_age() to `static` then it compiles and links without any problem. I didn't understand why it works with `static`.

The guards for the header files are proper, so no way it can be included multiple times, or I'm missing any thing here ?

Thank you,

Haridas N.

Comment: Good work on the testcase. It could still be stripped down further, but I'm glad to see that you essentially "got it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `get_age` in a header. That means it is copied into each translation unit, by the `#include` you have in each `.cpp`.

When you mark it `static` in namespace scope, that makes each copy "local" to that translation unit so no conflict occurs.

If you marked it `inline`, you'd be promising the compiler and linker that the definition is the same in each translation unit (which we can see it is) so the multiple copies would be magically rolled up into just one.

The proper approach, though, is to *declare* in your header and *define* in one source file, as you do with your class's member functions.

Comment: I was missing the translation unit. Thanks for the different solutions.

Comment: In case of generic functions or methods, the translation unit gets constructed specifically for that source by applying required types to the template right ? So is there any change the linker can see two object file has same function ?

Comment: @HaridasN: Translation units are not constructed from templates - it is a term that describes the code contained within a single `.cpp` and all the things you `#include`d into it (conventionally). These are each compiled separately, then finally the resulting object files are linked together. Not sure I understand your final question...

Answer (score 3):

When you include the `client.hpp` file, the `get_age` function is *defined*. And if you include the header file in more than one source file then you will have more than one definition of this function.

What you should do is to *declare* the function in the header file, and then define it in a single source file.

So in the header file do only

```
namespace work {
namespace test {

    int get_age();
}
}
```

And create the definition in a source file

```
int work::test::get_age() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you [could](http://ideone.com/HRFPCy) use nested-name-specifiers in function definitions like that. Excellent.

Comment: One doubt is, The guards for the header files are getting used while constructing one object file right ?, ie; it avoids duplicate definition in one object file. is that why guards not enough in my scenario ?

Comment: @HaridasN The header guards protects agains multiple inclusion in the same source file only. You might want to read about [translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Really that was I'm missing. I got it now, Thank you. Since LightnessRacesinOrbit's answer has more details.. I was accepted It.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function `inline` (as you've provided the implementation in the header...)